# API distance matrix Call in Javascript alone

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es, google-distancematrix-api

So I am an extremely beginner programmer trying to understand how to call/get data from Google Distance Matrix API in purely Javascript.

Below is my codes

```
https = require('https')

function getDistance(app){

    console.log('testing1');
    let defaultPath = 'maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric';
    let APIKey = '&key=<API KEY HERE>';
    let origin = 'Tampines Avenue 1, Temasek Polytechnic';
    let destination = 'Tampines Central 5, Tampines Mall';
    let newPath = defaultPath+ '&origins=' + origin + '&destinations=' +destination + APIKey;

    console.log('https://'+ newPath); //this prints the correct path

https.get('https://'+ newPath, (res) =>{ //i assume the problem begins here?

  console.log('testing2')//doesnt print

  let body = ''; //no idea what this does. Copied from a school lab sheet

  res.on('data', (d) => { 
    console.log('testing3') //this doesn't print
    let response = JSON.parse(body);

    let distance = response.rows[0].elements.distance.text //are these correct?
    let travelTime = response.rows[0].elements.duration.text 

    console.log(distance) //doesnt print
    console.log(response.rows[0]) //doesnt print

    app.add('distance between is ' + distance + '. Time taken is ' + travelTime);
    console.log(response);
  });
});
```

}

I'm pretty sure the 'https://'+ newPath is correct as it is printed in the console.log

And throwing the link into a browser
I get this as result

[image]

so can someone please explain to me what i'm doing wrong?
Oh and also, dont know if this is necessary but im doing this in dialogflow.cloud.google.com as a chatbot for my assignment

This is the error I get

> Error: No responses defined for platform: undefined at
>   WebhookClient.send_
>   (/srv/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:428:13)
>   at promise.then
>   (/srv/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:246:38)
>   at  at process._tickDomainCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)

Comment: Can you tell us what the problem is?

Comment: @LajosArpad "Problem begins here" stated in the comments of the codes.
nothing works past that line of "https.get('https://'+ newPath, (res) =>{"

Comment: Are you doing this in browser-based JavaScript, or in server-based NodeJS?  And what errors do you get? Do you know how to check for errors? "Nothing works" isn't a problem we can fix...we need specific details about an error message, or a description of some unexpected behaviour of the program.

Comment: This is the error i get

Error: No responses defined for platform: undefined
    at WebhookClient.send_ (/srv/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:428:13)
    at promise.then (/srv/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:246:38)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar problem on GitHub: https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/issues/22

The solution was

Okay, so here's what I did to make this work properly.

I used request-promise-native instead of http to make the AJAX Call.

```
const rp = require('request-promise-native');
```

I returned a promise from the handler of the promise that rp returns.

```
return rp(options).then(data => { // Extract relevant details from data. // Add it to the agent. agent.add('Here's the data: ', JSON.stringify(data)); return Promise.resolve(agent); });
```

The full code is

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const rp = require('request-promise-native');

const { WebhookClient } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const { Card, Suggestion } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const { Carousel } = require('actions-on-google');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

const imageUrl = 'https://developers.google.com/actions/images/badges/XPM_BADGING_GoogleAssistant_VER.png';
const imageUrl2 = 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Nu3a6F80WfixUqf_ec_vgXy_c0-0r4VLJRXjVFF_X_CIilEu8B9fT35qyTEj_PEsKw';
const linkUrl = 'https://assistant.google.com/';
const API_KEY = 'YOUR-API-KEY-HERE';

const server = express();

server.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  })
);
server.use(bodyParser.json());

server.post('/dialog-flow-fulfillment', (request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

  function googleAssistantOther(agent) {
    let conv = agent.conv();
    conv.ask(`Sure! Details about ${agent.parameters.movie} coming your way!`);
    return getMovieDataFromOMDb(agent.parameters.movie).then(movie => {
      conv.ask(`Okay! So there you go.`);
      conv.ask(new Card({
        title: `${movie.Title}(${movie.Year})`,
        imageUrl: movie.Poster,
        text: `${movie.Rated} | ${movie.Runtime} | ${movie.Genre} | ${movie.Released} (${movie.Country})`,
        buttonText: 'Website',
        buttonUrl: movie.Website || `https://www.imdb.com/title/${movie.imdbID}`
      }));
      conv.ask(new Suggestion(`More details`));
      conv.ask(new Suggestion(`Another movie`));
      agent.add(conv);
      return Promise.resolve(agent);
    });
  }

  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
  }

  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
  }

  function getMovieDetailsOther(agent) {
    return getMovieDataFromOMDb(agent.parameters.movie).then(movie => {
      // const responseDataToSend = `${movie.Title} is a ${
      //   movie.Actors
      // } starer ${movie.Genre} movie, released in ${
      //   movie.Year
      // }. It was directed by ${movie.Director}`;
      // console.log(`Generated response as ${responseDataToSend}`);
      // agent.add(responseDataToSend);

      agent.add(`Okay! So there you go.`);
      agent.add(new Card({
        title: `${movie.Title}(${movie.Year})`,
        imageUrl: movie.Poster,
        text: `${movie.Rated} | ${movie.Runtime} | ${movie.Genre} | ${movie.Released} (${movie.Country})`,
        buttonText: 'Website',
        buttonUrl: movie.Website || `https://www.imdb.com/title/${movie.imdbID}`
      }));
      agent.add(new Suggestion(`More details`));
      agent.add(new Suggestion(`Another movie`));
      return Promise.resolve(agent);
    }, error => {
      console.log(`Got an error as ${error}`);
      agent.add(`Sorry bout that! An error prevented getting data for: ${agent.parameters.movie || 'the requested movie'}`
      );
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log(`Caught an err as ${err}`);
      agent.add(err);
    });

    // agent.add(`This message is from Dialogflow's Cloud Functions for Firebase editor!`);
    // const newCard = new Card({
    //     title: `Title: this is a card title`,
    //     imageUrl: imageUrl,
    //     text: `This is the body text of a card.  You can even use line\n  breaks and emoji! `,
    //     buttonText: 'This is a button',
    //     buttonUrl: linkUrl
    // });
    // // newCard.setPlatform('facebook');
    // agent.add(newCard);
    // agent.add(new Suggestion(`Quick Reply`));
    // agent.add(new Suggestion(`Suggestion`));
    // agent.setContext({ name: 'weather', lifespan: 2, parameters: { city: 'Rome' }});
  }

  function moreDetailsOther(agent) {
    return getMovieDataFromOMDb(agent.parameters.movie).then(movie => {
      agent.add(`Okay! I've got you covered on this too.`);
      agent.add(`So the ${movie.Actors} starer ${movie.Type} is produced by ${movie.Production}, is directed by ${movie.Director}`);
      agent.add(`It ${movie.Awards}. It's available in ${movie.Language}`);
      agent.add(`Written by ${movie.Writer}, it plots ${movie.Plot}`);
      agent.add(new Suggestion(`Stats on the movie`));
      agent.add(new Suggestion(`Another movie`));
      return Promise.resolve(agent);
    }, error => {
      console.log(`Got an error as ${error}`);
      agent.add(`Sorry bout that! An error prevented getting data for: ${agent.parameters.movie || 'the requested movie'}`
      );
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log(`Caught an err as ${err}`);
      agent.add(err);
    });
  }

  function movieStatsOther(agent) {
    return getMovieDataFromOMDb(agent.parameters.movie).then(movie => {
      let ratingDetails = `${movie.Title} scored `;
      movie.Ratings.forEach(rating => {
        ratingDetails += `${rating.Value} on ${rating.Source} `
      });
      agent.add(`Sure! Here are the stats.`);
      agent.add(ratingDetails);
      agent.add(new Suggestion(`Another movie`));
      return Promise.resolve(agent);
    }, error => {
      console.log(`Got an error as ${error}`);
      agent.add(`Sorry bout that! An error prevented getting data for: ${agent.parameters.movie || 'the requested movie'}`
      );
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log(`Caught an err as ${err}`);
      agent.add(err);
    });
  }

  function getMovieDataFromOMDb(movieName) {
    const movieToSearch = movieName || 'The Godfather';
    const options = {
      uri: 'https://www.omdbapi.com/',
      json: true,
      qs: {
        t: movieToSearch,
        apikey: API_KEY
      }
    };
    return rp(options);
  }

  // Run the proper handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  if (agent.requestSource === agent.ACTIONS_ON_GOOGLE) {
    intentMap.set(null, googleAssistantOther);
    // intentMap.set('More Details', googleAssistantMoreDetails);
    // intentMap.set('Movie Stats', googleAssistantMovieStats);
  } else {
    intentMap.set('Get Movie Details', getMovieDetailsOther);
    intentMap.set('More Details', moreDetailsOther);
    intentMap.set('Movie Stats', movieStatsOther);
  }
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 8000, () => {
  console.log('Server is up and running...');
});
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/siddajmera/pen/eraNLW?editors=0010

Comment: I get an error when i use this "const rp = require('request-promise-native');" Error says "he deployment of your Cloud Function failed: Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Code in file index.js can't be loaded. Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies? Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'request-promise-native'"

Comment: @CobenYap please take a look at the steps described in the link I give you now. The installation steps are described there: https://github.com/request/request-promise-native

Answer (score 0):

You don't show all your code, but it looks like `getDistance()` is your Intent Handler function that you've registered in code that you're not showing.

If so, and if you're making an asynchronous call to an API, you need to return a Promise to indicate that you're waiting for the HTTP call to complete before you send the result.

Without the Promise, the function completes right after it makes the call with `http.get()`, but without anything being set for the response with `app.add()`.

While it is possible to turn an event-based call (what you're doing now) into a Promise, it isn't that easy if you're not familiar with it, and there are better solutions.

Using a package such as [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) (and more likely request-promise-native - it uses the same syntax, but request-promise has the documentation) is far easier. With this, you would return the Promise that is generated by the http call, and in the `then()` clause of it, you would make your calls to `app.add()`.

I haven't tested it, but it might look something like this:

```
const rp = require('request-promise-native');

function getDistance(app){

    console.log('testing1');
    let defaultPath = 'maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric';
    let APIKey = '&key=<API KEY HERE>';
    let origin = 'Tampines Avenue 1, Temasek Polytechnic';
    let destination = 'Tampines Central 5, Tampines Mall';
    let newPath = defaultPath+ '&origins=' + origin + '&destinations=' +destination + APIKey;
    let url = 'https://'+newPath;

    console.log(url);

    rp.get(url)
      .then( response => {
        console.log(response);
        let distance = response.rows[0].elements.distance.text
        let travelTime = response.rows[0].elements.duration.text 

        app.add('distance between is ' + distance + '. Time taken is ' + travelTime);
      })
      .catch( err => {
        console.log( err );
        app.add('Something went wrong.');
      });

};
```

Comment: I get an error when i use this "const rp = require('request-promise-native');"
Error says "he deployment of your Cloud Function failed:
Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'request-promise-native'"

Comment: As the error suggests - you will need to list the package dependencies in your `package.json` file.